# How to far jump to $0x9000:%ax using AT&T syntax?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86, bootloader, att

I'm writing a toy os to learn the workings of it, here I came into a little problem. I want to do a long jump, just as follows:

```
ljmp $0x9000, *(%ax)
```

The section address is 0x9000, the offset address is stored in the register `ax` (currently I'm still under real mode), I've tried the following, none of them worked.

```
ljmp $0x9000, ax
ljmp $0x9000, %ax
ljmp $0x9000, (%ax)
ljmp $0x9000, *(%ax)
```

So how to do the trick? I'm using GNU AS (i686-elf-as).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to "nrz"'s method you may also push 0x9000 and AX and perform a RETF:

```
pushw $0x9000
push %ax
retf
```

Note: On original 8086s and 8088s even the "pushw $xxxx" instruction does not exist...

Answer (score 2):

In x86 there is no such instruction you are attempting to do. What you need to do is to store the memory address `0x9000:ax` into memory and then do an indirect jump to that address.

The indirect jump is this one ([Intel® 64 and IA-32 architectures software developer's manual combined volumes: 1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 3A, 3B, and 3C](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)):

```
FF /5 JMP m16:16 Jump far, absolute indirect, address given in m16:16
```

So the code should be something like this:

```
.code16
movw $0x9000, ($jump_address_segment)
movw %ax, ($jump_address_offset)
ljmp *($jump_address_offset)

.data
jump_address_offset:  .word 0
jump_address_segment: .word 0
```